# Transfer large amount of data from a SQL Server database to MongoDB periodically

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, c#-4.0

I have a table in a SQL Server database which contains large amount of data, around 2 million records (~approx 20 columns for each row). The data in this table gets overridden at the end of each day with new data.

Once the new data is available I need to copy this data from the SQL Server database to a MongoDB table.

The question is on the way by which it can be achieved the fastest?

Some options :

- A simple application that reads and writes
- Some sort of export/import tool.
- Generating a\multiple file\s from SQL and then reading concurrently to import in MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

From my expirience:

> A simple application that reads and writes.

Will be the slowest.

> Some sort of export/import tool.

Should be much faster than the first option. Take a look at the [bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx) utility to export data from SQL and then import data with [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#bin.mongoimport). However, the way you store data in mongo might differ a lot from the SQL one so it might be quite a challenge to do the mapping with export/import tools.

> Generating a\multiple file\s from SQL and then reading concurrently to
>   import in MongoDB

Paralleling might speed up the procees a bit but I don't think you will be satisfied with the results.

From your question the data gets overriden at the end of each day. Not sure how you do it now but I think it makes sense to write data to both SQL and Mongo at that time. This way you won't have to query the data from SQL again to update Mongo. You will be just writing to mongo at the same time you are updating SQL.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response and apologies for not getting back earlier.              Actually during the day the data keeps on accumulating and at a particular time all the data from various sources involving complex business logic gets copied to a SQL table. Only after that we can write in Mongo, so unfortunately directly writing to Mongo wont work.

Comment: Is there something which has been done and tested before?

Comment: could you please elaborate on how you write data to SQL? I'm particualrly interested in the last step when you have data ready and just need to push it to SQL db. Also a few words on why you need the data to be duplicated in mongo would be helpful